# Adding rows to LinearLayouts which serve as lists

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment with a `ScrollView` and, inside of it, I need maybe 5 or 6 lists. To make things simpler, let's say there are three lists - list of names, list of places and list of events.

The problem is, I can't use lists inside of `ScrollView`s so I need to use `LinearLayout`s and do the adding to the list thing by myself. This causes me all sorts of problems.

I'm using index variables to keep track of where in my layout to put the new row when the user clicks "Add".

```
int currIndNames;
int currIndPlaces;
int currIndEvents;
```

Now this is my `onCreate` function:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        names = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("names");
        places = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("places");
        events = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("events");
    } else {
        if (names == null){
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        };
        if (places == null){
            places = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        if (events == null){
            events = new ArrayList<String>();
        }            
    }

    realNames = new LinkedHashSet<>(names);
    realPlaces = new LinkedHashSet<>(places);
    realEvents = new LinkedHashSet<>(events);
}
```

The "real" variables are there because I didn't find a way to put sets into `savedInstanceState`, so I keep each group of items both in a set and in a list.

Now, in my `onViewCreated` method, I'm calling `prepareNames`, `preparePlaces` and `prepareEvents`. The names are the first list in the layout, so the function looks something like this:

```
private void prepareNames(){

  edtAddName = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edtName);

  LinearLayout linearLayoutNames = (LinearLayout)getActivity().
            findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutNamesTitle);


    currIndNames = ((ViewGroup)linearLayout).indexOfChild(linearLayoutNames)+1;

    for (String name: names){
        addNamesRow(name, currIndNames++);
        currIndPlaces++;
        currIndEvents++;
    }

    prepareToggleButtonNames();
    prepareButtonAddName();
    prepareButtonNames();

}
```

Now, as you see, after adding the names row, I also have to increase the indexes for places and events, because they're further down in the linear layout.

Furthermore, users can remove rows, and I have to do something similar when removing rows. This is my `addNamesRow` function:

```
private void addNamesRow(final String text, int position){
    final LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout)LinearLayout.inflate(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.item,null);

    rowLayout.setTag(NAMES_TAG);

    TextView tvItem = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.tv_item);
    tvItem.setText(text);

    Spinner spItem = (Spinner)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.sp_item);
    spItem.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.array.ratings,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item));
    spItem.setSelection(2);


    Button btnItem = (Button)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_item);
    btnItem.setText("X");
    btnItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currIndNames--;
            currIndPlaces--;
            currIndEvents--;
            linearLayout.removeView(rowLayout);
            realNames.remove(text);
        }
    });

    linearLayout.addView(rowLayout, position);

    linearLayout.invalidate();
    edtAddName.setText("");
}
```

My code works but I have a lot of duplication and it's very messy. I have some ideas on how to avoid some of the repetition but I'm new to Android development and I feel like I have some deeper issues in my code, and I would like to do things the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems in code seem to be a manifestation of problematic design. If I were you I would think about improving my design first.

Currently you're displaying a list of lists of variable lengths to your user. From a UX point of view that seems like a bad decision.

**There's a reason why you can't use lists in a `ScrollView` ;)**

Have you considered for example splitting up the lists to different fragments and putting them in a view pager so you have a separate tab for each list? Then you can use `ListView` or, probably even better, `RecyclerView` to display your items.

Again a lot of times when you have to write awkward, messy code to implement your design it is worth revisiting your design and improving it. Usually that clears up convoluted code as well.